# Appropriate Test of Significance for Eye Tracking Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

Hello my clever friends,

I conducted an eye-tracking study and now I'm in statistical hot water. Given the characteristics of the data, I am not sure which test of significance to apply to answer the research questions. I would greatly appreciate your wisdom in these statistical matters.

I recorded the eye fixations of 45 participants (16 males, 29 females) as they navigated a desktop virtual environment. The participants engaged in a search task with a time limit of 3 minutes, but most participants completed the task in under three minutes. Each participant completed 10 trials. The recorded eye-tracking data consisted of the fixation time that participants spent looking at either the top or the bottom region of the screen during each trial.

Here's a sample of the fixation data for one participant across the 10 trials. The data represents the amount of time in seconds that the participant spent fixating on the bottom and top regions of the screen.

Top

**T1:** 2.97
**T2:** 5.52
**T3:** 17.83
**T4:** 0.0
**T5:** 0.0
**T6:** 7.72
**T7:** 3.72
**T8:** .00
**T9:** .01
**T10:** 2.23

Bottom

**T1:** 87.92
**T2:** 85.90
**T3:** 90.22
**T4:** 176.65
**T5:** 172.65
**T6:** 69.0
**T7:** 46.43
**T8:** 121.43
**T9:** 173.28
**T10:** 18.77

Notice that most fixation time was allocated to the bottom portion of the screen, and on some trials the participant did not even look at the top area.

I am interested in analyzing the aggregated data across all 10 trials (not trial by trial) based on the sex of the participant. My research questions are as follows:

1. Is the **percentage** of fixation time allocated to the bottom region of the screen by males significantly different than 50%? Likewise for females.
2. Is the percentage of fixation time allocated to the bottom region of the screen significantly different between males and females?

In past research conducted by other researchers, they used a one sample t-test to answer #1 and an independent sample t-test to answer #2. There are some reasons why I don't think I can do that. Notice that most of the fixation time was allocated to the bottom region and in some cases, the top region was not observed. This skews the data and makes them non-normal and possibly non-homogenous. Secondly, past analysis was only based on the first few seconds and it was the same time limit for everyone. I am analyzing the entire session, which varies from participant to participant.

What tests should I use for these data?
Is there a non-parametric equivalent to the t-test that I can use on percentage data?
How should I calculate the percentages given that each participant spent a different amount of time completing the task?

I am using SPSS to analyze the data, so recommendations on how to run the procedures would be much welcomed.

Comment: Is it possible to fixate on the middle of the screen, or are they either looking at the top or bottom? (Ie, are there more than 2 zones?)

Comment: There are only two zones- top and bottom.

Comment: So, eg, 2.97 (seconds?) + 87.92 = 90.89 is the total time for trial 1? & .967 is the % time fixated on the bottom?

Comment: To clarify, the times that I posted represent only 'viewing' time, not the time actually spent completing the task. For example, in trial 1 the participant may have spent 100 seconds in the environment searching for a target, but the eye tracker only recorded 90.89 seconds of fixation time as you quoted. So this represent the total _fixation_ time. Yes, .967 is the correct proportion for the bottom area for this participant.

Comment: So some part of the task doesn't require 'viewing', but you don't care about that? The only relevant datum from this trial for the purpose of testing your hypotheses is the 90.89 seconds? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.